# How do I start a Liberty server in debug mode in the background with the liberty-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

### Use Case

The [liberty-maven-plugin](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven) has a [debug](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven/blob/master/docs/debug-server.md) goal which allows you to start the server in debug mode, but in the *foreground*.

Often when wanting to attach the debugger, this is all you'd need.  You can execute tests separately somehow or via other goals launched from another shell.

But the **debug** goal, like the [run](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven/blob/master/docs/run-server.md) goal, runs in the foreground and blocks until the server process completes.

If I want to continue to the next phase of my build, e.g. on to run integration tests, it could help to configure a [start](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven/blob/master/docs/start-server.md) goal to start the server in debug mode, in the background, and continue on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use:  src/test/resources/jvm.options

In **src/test/resources/jvm.options**, for example:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=7777
```

This is the default value for the `<jvmOptionsFile>` configuration parameter (described [here](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven/blob/master/docs/common-server-parameters.md#common-server-parameters)), so of course you could configure a different location if desired.

#### Note:

Though an alternative might appear to be to use the `<jvmOptions>` configuration, it does not work well with the commas (',')  embedded in this value.

### Warning:

You may be expecting a message from the starting JVM:

`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 7777`

However you will not see this from your Maven execution log, it actually appears in the **console.log** file of the configured server.  So the Maven execution will just pause at the point of logging message:

`[INFO] Starting server defaultServer.`

If you fail to connect in time you'll see:

`[INFO] Server defaultServer start failed. Check server logs for details.`